# javascript Alert isn't working from inside getjson function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, alert, getjson

I have this script that creates a table from a json file. Each row has a clickale element that loads another json file. When the second json file loads I want to alert the user, but with the script I have the alert isnt working. What am I doing wrong? I am very new to javascript so it might just be a simple mistake.

```
  $.each(result["auctionInfo"], function(i, player){
    $("#curAuctions").append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td>' + player["sellerName"] + "</td><td>" + style[player["itemData"]["playStyle"]] + "</td><td>" + player["itemData"]["preferredPosition"] + "</td><td>" + player["itemData"]["injuryType"] + "</td><td>" + player["itemData"]["contract"] + "</td><td>" + player["startingBid"] + '</td><td>'  + player["buyNowPrice"] + '</td><td><div id="countdown'+i+'"></div></td><td style="text-align:center;" ><a id="buy'+i+'" data-id="'+ player["tradeId"] +'" data-price="'+ player["buyNowPrice"] +'" title="" class="button greenB" style="margin: 5px;"><span>Buy</span></a></td></tr>');
    $('#countdown'+i).countdown({until: +player["expires"], format: 'HMS', compact: true});
    $("#activeTable").tablesorter();
    $( "#buy"+i ).bind( "click", function() {
        $(this).replaceWith('<img src="images/loaders/loader.gif" alt="" style="margin: 14px;">');
        $.getJSON("auction.php?action=buy&player=" + player["tradeId"] +"&value="+ player["buyNowPrice"], function(result){

            alert("request finished");
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong with the javascript, your php script simply isn't returning valid json.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: ok so  $.getJSON("", function(result){}); only runs the callback if it finds json?

Comment: Correct. If json isn't returned, the error callback is called rather than the success.

Comment: Thanks kevin, the problem was cause in the php script. it works now